# Что получается в результате выполения func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));

Tags: javascript

```
function sum() {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
}

function mul() {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  });
}

function applyAll(func) {
    return func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
  }

alert( applyAll(sum, 1, 2, 3) ); // 6
alert( applyAll(mul, 2, 3, 4) ); // 24
alert( applyAll(Math.max, 2, -2, 3) ); // 3
alert( applyAll(Math.min, 2, -2, 3) ); // -2
```

помогите понять код...а именно эти строки

```
return func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));

return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
});
```

Comment: Покажите код полностью, в конце у вас он обрезан. И что вы хотите, что бы вам рассказали что значат эти строки?

Comment: @Mr_Epic, это куски кода из фрагмента выше. Кода достаточно.

Comment: это полный код, да, я не понимаю эти строки...

Comment: проблема с этой функцией function applyAll(func) {
    return func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
  }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> return func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
> ```

От `arguments` отрезается первый аргумент (это `func`), а хвост (`[].slice.call(arguments, 1)`) передаётся в `apply`.

```
var a = [func, 1, 2, 4];
a.slice(1); // [1, 2, 4]
```

Поскольку `arguments` - это не настоящий массив, то `arguments.slice` использовать нельзя, поскольку такого метода нет. Вместо этого к ним применяется метод массива `Array.prototype.slice` - в более короткой записи `[].slice` - доступ через ненужный инстанс вместо непосредственного.

> ```
> return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
>   return a + b;
> });
> ```

Обычное применение функции [`reduce`](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). По той же причине, что и выше, вызов через метод ненужного массива.